# Force img size with svg source

Tags: html, css, svg

I've got a flag thing that is supposed to display flags like this: [image]

But instead I get this: [image]

But not all the time. Just sometimes. It appears it's random. But the second version occurs much more.
Maybe has something to do with cache?

This is my code:

```
   <img
          alt={`Flag ${name}`}
          src={`https://lipis.github.io/flag-icon-css/flags/4x3/${name.toLowerCase()}.svg`}
          width="75px"
          height="50px"
        />
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Including more of your HTML and JavaScript would be helpful, like for the `name` variable. Also consider setting up a [code snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) which helps with debugging CSS issues.

Comment: Did you try to play with object-fit: cover/contain ?

Comment: Can you share the link of the website or some more code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fixed it by setting the minWidth attribute to 75px.